# How to get values from a specific cell from many Excel files for a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, date, excel-formula, getvalue

I have some Excel files named by date, let's say from "2022-02-01.xlsx" to "2022-02-28.xlsx"
How can I get values from a specific cell (e.g.: A1) from all these files for a worksheet (a master files)?
I don't want to open these reports. I just want to update data from those files to the master files.

Comment: This is one of the few defensible uses of INDIRECT perhaps?

Comment: Look at the `GetCellMacro` function here: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/copy-a-cell-value-from-multiple-closed-workbooks-into-a-new-workbook.988774/#post4746272

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the code below will work to other Excel version.
The code below works with my Excel 2010

```
Sub test()

p = "D:\test\" 'the path where all the files of the wb
s = "Sheet1" 'the sheet where the cell has the value wanted to know
c = "A1" '---> the cell where the value is wanted to know

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(p)

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    f = oFile.Name
    VL = "'" & p & "[" & f & "]" & _
          s & "'!" & Range(c).Address(True, True, -4150)
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
    oFile.Name & " cell A1 value is " & ExecuteExcel4Macro(VL)
Next

End Sub
```

[image]